# How to add items using Lists to Dictionary without looping through it?

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-4.0

I have this Dictionary-

```
IDictionary<DateTime, int> kamptslist = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();
List<int> listints= GetListofints(); //for values
List<int> listdates= GetListofdates();// for keys
```

Can I somehow assign the lists directly to the Dictionary instead of actually doing a `foreach` and adding one item at a time ?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) to zip the two sequences together, and then use `Enumerable.ToDictionary`:

```
var kamptslist = listdates.Zip(listints, (d, n) => Tuple.Create(d, n))
                          .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);
```

Comment: I prefer using an anonymous type here, as then you can see what's going to be a key more easily.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Oh, I don't know about that. You have to know which parameter is the key, and which is the value in `ToDictionary` anyway. I suppose that you could use named parameters to make it clear but without that just using an anonymous type doesn't make it more clear IMO.

Comment: Yes, although Intellisense shows you that while you're writing it. Put it this way: *I* find it simpler to see what's going on with my code than with yours - but that's to be expected, of course :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: That's true about IntelliSense while you're writing it, but usually not available if you're browsing code in a Git/Mercurial repository, or during a code review, for example. I do agree with your last point.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this easily with .NET 4:

```
var dictionary = listints.Zip(listdates, (value, key) => new { value, key })
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);
```

Without .NET 4 it's a bit harder, although you could always use a grotty hack:

```
var dictionary = Enumerable.Range(0, listints.Count)
                           .ToDictionary(i => listdates[i], i => listints[i]);
```

EDIT: As per comment, this works fine with an explicitly typed variable to:

```
IDictionary<DateTime, int> kamptslist = 
     listints.Zip(listdates, (value, key) => new { value, key })
             .ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);
```

Comment: @Misnomer: You can explicitly declare the variable, yes - in both cases it'll really *be* a `Dictionary<DateTime, int>` though.

Answer (score 0):

```
IDictionary<DateTime, int> kamptslist = GetListofdates()
    .Zip(
        GetListofints(), 
        (date, value) => new { date, value })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.date, x => x.value);
```